# What does Express $A_N$ in terms of $F_N$ mean with the Fibonacci Sequence?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

The problem is: Consider the Fibonacci-like sequence $5,5,10,15,25,40, \ldots$ and let $A_N$ denote the $N$th term of the sequence.

The questions are:

1. Find $A_{10}$
2. Given that $F_{25} = 75,025$, find $A_{25}$.

And now the question that is confusing me:

3. Express $A_N$ in terms of $F_N$

Comment: How did you do part 2? Did you use the fact that $F_{25}=75025,$ or did you ignore that piece of information and just work out the next $15$ terms of the sequence after $A_{10}$?

Comment: I ignored that and just worked out the numbers after A10 yeah.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Try multiplying each term of the original Fibonacci sequence, $F_N$,

$$ 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, \ldots $$

by $5$ and compare with $A_N$.